# .htaccess redirect folder and subfolder except for some subfolders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i have a problem with my .htaccess
I want to redirect any page and subfolder in the folder /w/ to the main page of my website, so i want to do something like this:

```
www.mysite.com/w/           - redirect -> www.mysite.com
www.mysite.com/w/subfolder/ - redirect -> www.mysite.com
```

But, i want to NOT redirect some subfolder like:

```
www.mysite.com/w/subfolder1 --> not redirect 
www.mysite.com/w/subfolder2 --> not redirect
```

My htaccess is:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /w/(?!subfolder1) /$1
```

But it doesn't work, i tried with:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /w/(?!^subfolder1) /$1
```

and

```
RedirectMatch 301 /w/(?!subfolder1$) /$1
```

But nothing was right!

Please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/w/((?!subfolder1|subfolder2).*) /$1
```

You can exclude more folders from the directive, just seperate them using a bar **|**